# What is it mean ? Casting address of variable to char. How come?

Tags: c, casting

What is it mean ?

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size = 2048;
    char *stack;

    stack = (char *) &size; // cast memory address of a variable to char
}
```

I really don't understand what it will be if we cast memory address of a variable.

Comment: Seems to be code written by somebody that does not have a good debugger.  Looking at the stack frame of a function is a bog standard feature.  Diving the real intention, well, who knows.  Ask him, not us.

Comment: @Oka Prinarjaya it means nothing because you did not show the actual code and the context where the casting is used.

Answer (score 2):

```
int size = 2048;
char *stack;
stack = (char *) &size; // cast memory address of a variable to char
```

- `size` is an `int` variable occupying a 4 byte memory block (typically).
- `&size` is therefore the address of that memory block.
- `char *stack = (char *)&size` meaning that `stack` is a pointer to char that points to the beginning of that 4-byte memory block.

Basically `*stack` is the first byte of the 4-byte int variable, the exact value is platform-dependent (depends on the machine endianness)

Comment: Still not clear fo rme. Because, i've try to printf("stack size = %d\n", sizeof(stack)); it print 8. how come? what is it holds actually.

Comment: `sizeof(stack)` is the size of a pointer. Typically in 64b machine you get 64b pointer which is 8 bytes.

Comment: Btw, dont use `%d` for `size_t`, use `%zu` instead